# Throwing and Catching Erros in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am familiar with java programing and throwing and catching errors and I am unsure if this is a functionality within excel VBA. I would like to do the following catching but unsure it is still not working

```
 If Workbooks("Name").Worksheets("Sheet1") Is Nothing Then
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 9, , "Destination Spreadsheet not Open. Please Open"
    End If
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Name").Worksheets("Sheet1")
```

However when I create this code I still run into the same "Subscript out of range error". If anyone has any advice or tips please let me know.

Comment: errors should be before the line, not after: In this case you need something like `On error resume next Set WS=Workbooks("Name").Worksheets("Sheet1")` then `If WS Is Nothing Then`

Comment: PS: Here you have [an article](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling/#:~:text=When%20an%20runtime%20error%20occurs,the%20Err%20object%20with%20details.&text=The%20Err.,only%20necessary%20on%20rare%20occasions.) that may give you a wider concept for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `on error goto` statement to handle this situation. A workbook and a worksheet are both contained in a collection, so any attempt to access a non-existent element will throw a subscript out of range error before you get to your `err.raise`.

```
     Dim wsdest As Worksheet
    On Error GoTo desterr
    Set wsdest = Workbooks("Name").Worksheets("Sheet1")
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
desterr:
    Err.Raise vbObjectError + 9, , "Destination Spreadsheet not Open. Please Open"
    
End Sub
```

If you're not a fan of that you could also try and loop through each workbook and worksheet to find what you are looking for, thought that would be a bit less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access an workbooks that don't exist, this error will raise. You can use this method to check all kind of collection.

```
Public Function CollectionItemObjectAvalible(p_Collection As Object, p_key As String)
   Dim l_val
   On Error Resume Next
   Set l_val = p_Collection(p_key)
   CollectionItemObjectAvalible = Err.Number = 0   'nur wenn oben der Zugriff keine Fehler erzeugt hat, ist das Objekt vorhanden
End Function

If CollectionItemObjectAvalible(Workbooks, "Name") Then
   Err.Raise vbObjectError + 1, "My Project", "Cannot find 'Name' in workbooks."
End If
```